# 'Const' is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi i need some help again with my discord moderation bot. This is the code behind the bot. (I comented the part that throws the error.)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const mySecret = process.env['BOT_TOKEN']
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "st!";
const verNumber = "1.0.3bc"
const dev = "567014451337887744"
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}.\n Ver: ${verNumber}\n Prefix: ${prefix} `);
  console.log('Bot ready for operation.')
  client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help for command list. | Using Current Branch`, {
    type: 'LISTENING'
 });
});
client.on('message', message => {
  console.log(`${message.author.tag} at ${message.guild.name} said: ${message.content}\n`);
  if (message.content == "fuck") {
    message.reply("Don't say bad words :(");
  }
});
client.on("message", function (message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);// it throws an error here
    const args = commandBody.split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    ...
```

and i don't understand why the bot breaks on const commandbody.
Can someone please help me?
The error:

```
    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)       
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Try `var` and see if it works. I do not understand why const is unexpected since it looks like good syntax. Maybe wrap your `return;`s in { and }?

Comment: instead of `message.content == ....` I'd at minimum change to `message.content.toLowerCase().includes(...)`. To cover more cases I'd make a function that can check a bunch of words with various spellings ... maybe from a file that can be easily updated

Comment: Although it's unrelated to your current issue: Only use one message event, using 2 or more will cause memory leaks.

Comment: Ok, so i found the bug, it was in my file. The line causing the problem wasn't const commandBody. Instead was if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) that was missing a return;